# MSWordAddin Connect Database

Tags: sql-server, connection

I am creating a MSWord Addin on visual studio 11. But I want to know how to connect it to the database. There is no configuration file where I can add a connection.

Please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do that visually you can do it in Data Sources Toolbox which is available in menu:

```
VIEW->Other Windows->Data Sources (Shift+Alt+D)
```

And then `Add New Data Source...`